# Opamps used in low voltage applications

Tags: operational-amplifier, low-voltage

1. How is it possible to use op amps on a supply of (+3v), for example: mp3 player and other battery operated devices?
2. What type of op amps do we use in low voltage applications?
3. How is it possible they have such a big output voltage in relation to the supply voltage?

This is my first time dealing with op amps in low voltage applications. I'm grateful for any kind of feedback.

Comment: Would you believe there are [opamps](http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/TS1001.pdf) that still work even on 0.65V?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is it possible to use opamps on a supply of (+3v), for example:
>   mp3 player and other battery operated devices?

Bipolar transistors in linear operation probably only need about 0.6 volts to operate properly at the base and maybe 1 volt across collector to emitter to yield a usable output voltage range. MOSFETs need a little more but not much more. Both/either are used in op-amps.

> what type of opamps do we use in low voltage applications?

We have to use what are called rail-to-rail opamps because these are specifically designed to maximize the range of the low voltage available for powering the device. "Rail" aka power supply rail or supply voltage.

> how is it possible they have such a big output voltages in relation to
>   the supply voltage?

They can only produce output voltages within the power supply range. For instance, if the power rails are 0V and 1.8 volts then the output will be limited to a range of 20 mV to 1.78 volts (under no-load conditions). Some are worse than others of course.

Answer (score 3):

They tend to be called rail to rail, or R2R amplifiers. They can be R2R on input only, output only, or both.

Many use CMOS internally, though bipolar designs also exist.

With low voltage gadgets, their creation has been a necessity. In the bad old days, high voltage rails were the norm (+/- 15v), and bipolar designs happily stayed a volt or three away from the rails. You can't do that with battery powered devices today.

Comment: *With low voltage gadgets, their creation has been a necessity.* I agree. Funny thing is that the reason why all these gadgets use low voltages is that they use very complex digital ICs which can only run on low voltages. At +/- 15 V the same high circuit complexity can never be reached on a chip. And low voltage operation is also easier regarding the battery voltage of course (no upconverter needed).

Answer (score 2):

> How is it possible to use opamps on a supply of (+3v), for example:
>   mp3 player and other battery operated devices?

A supply voltage of 3.3V is actually quite high for integrated circuits. Voltages on the order of 1.2V to 3.3V are quite common.

> what type of opamps do we use in low voltage applications?

The input stage is often standard, since the common-mode voltage can be set to a fixed level.

The final stage of such an opamp looks like an inverter (push-pull stage). The tricky part is controlling the quiescent current. Such output stages are called rail-to-rail.

> how is it possible they have such a big output voltages in relation to the ?supply voltage?

Outputs are differential. We don't have one output fixed at 0V and the other moving, but both outputs moving up and down. So the amplitude can be almost equal to the supply voltage. This gives four times the output power compared to a single-ended output.

If that's not enough a boost converter is required. For a given load impedance and output power a certain voltage is needed. There is no way around that.

For audio (MP3 players, if they still exist) the output signal is usually generated using a class-D amplifier. Here the output is switched on and off to generate a PWM signal, which results in a higher efficiency.